Razor pages SQL Server backend drop column
I'm having issues with the backend of my Razor pages SQL Server database. I'm new to programming and I'm having problems finding where the ValidationId is still be referenced in the program. When I run a search on the entire program there is no occurrences of it anywhere within the program.
Stack trace:
SqlException: Invalid column name 'ValidationId'.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__211_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask<TAntecedentResult, TResult>.InnerInvoke()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HPMS.Pages.FeatureClasses.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in Index.cshtml.cs
+
            FeatureClass = await _context.FeatureClass.ToListAsync();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Feature class model:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using HPMS.Models;

namespace HPMS.Models;

public class FeatureClass
{ 
    public int Id { get; set;  }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public string connectionString { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public string truncatedConnectionString { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required] // Required parameter
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}   

Feature class Index page:
@page
@model HPMS.Pages.FeatureClasses.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeatureClass[0].Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeatureClass[0].connectionString)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeatureClass[0].truncatedConnectionString)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeatureClass[0].Description)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.FeatureClass) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.connectionString)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.truncatedConnectionString)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

Code-behind file:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using HPMS.Data;
using HPMS.Models;

namespace HPMS.Pages.FeatureClasses
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly HPMS.Data.HPMSContext _context;

        public IndexModel(HPMS.Data.HPMSContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<FeatureClass> FeatureClass { get;set; } = default!;

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            FeatureClass = await _context.FeatureClass.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}

Feature class table set up:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FeatureClass] 
(
    [Id]                        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [connectionString]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [truncatedConnectionString] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Description]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_FeatureClass] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Originally ValidationId was a foreign key of the FeatureClass table. I (attempted) to remove all references to ValidationId, but evidently one still exists though I've looked everywhere throughout the program and cannot find anything, could it potentially be a caching issue?

Use something like Notepad++ to search within files of your project. Sometimes a reference gets orphaned in files that aren't searched by visual studio text search utility. Notepad++ has a feature called "find in files" that will search all files for a specified search term.

Have you tried a "Rebuild Solution" command instead of just 'Build Solution"? Or explicitly "Clean Solution" and then rebuilding it?

I have tried this with no solution yet, I searched in Notepad++ but the only occurrences which it is finding is within Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll within the Debug folder.

Empty the Debug folder and build again.

Have you created the DbSchema by Migration or manually designed the Database table? What's your .NET version? In addition, If the application uses caching mechanisms that store schema information, it could be pulling old metadata. Restarting the application and clearing any application-level caches might resolve this.

Do you have another class that has a FeatureClass as navigation property? If so, EF Core expects the FeatureClass table to have a foreign key even though you haven't got one in the model.

In the future you should run all db changes through EF's migrations.  It sounds like you may have manually removed the field.  You could try manually adding it back to the DB and then modifying code/running a migration to remove it again.  (always proceed with caution when removing data whether it's manually or through migrations... I try to avoid doing any destructive migrations)

Migrations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Maybe an old version of your page that references ValidationId  has been cached by your browser.
